# ASP.NET MVC setting src of iframe in javascript - document not visible

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to build a ASP.NET MVC webpage wherein I have a use an iframe to view a local document.

(I am changing the src attribute on a button click)

But on setting the src attribute of the iframe in javascript, the document is not shown in the webpage. On inspecting the iframe element in chrome, I found the src has been correctly set but the document is still not displayed; the browser shows the message :

```
"local resource cannot be opened"
```

I tried the example is a simple html page setting the src attribute of an iframe, and the document is getting displayed.

Can anyone suggest a solution.

Thanks.

Comment: What document are you trying to display? How does the `src` attribute of the iframe look like?

Comment: The document is a word doc saved as .htm format. I am setting the src to the absolute path of the .htm file on my machine (C:\Temp\test.htm).

Answer (score 0):

Here's my own answer:

The problem was that I had an actual path of the document, but when the page loads, the document was not being found under localhost.

After moving the document to the appropriate location in the MVC folder hierarchy ( I pasted my document in Content folder ), the src was set as

```
// root has the value : Content

// docname is my document : test.htm

var path = root + docname ;

iframe.src = "../" + path ;
```

This make the overall path in the src : http://localhost/Content/test.htm